# ref completion in latex suite

Tags: vim, grep, completion, latex-suite

When I press <kbd>f9</kbd> at `\ref{` in vim with latex suite plugin, I just get an error saying

> E484: Can't open file C:/Temp/tempfilename.tmp

When I went to the location, `tempfilename.tmp` was not there. I assumed this file is the result of calling grep.

However, when I manually used `:!grep -nH ref myfile.tex >C:/Temp/tempfilename.tmp &2>1` in vim and it worked fine. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Potentially better suited for [vi.se]?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try there.